# Powershell Script to Search files with extensions

Tags: powershell

I have created a simple PowerShell script to search files on a particular directory path which will show files larger than 100MB. It will take the output into a csv file as well.Here is the script i use

```
Get-childitem -path "C:\Users\someuser" -Include *.db,*.bak,*.mdf,*.ldf,*.zip,*.rar,*.7z -recurse | where-object {$_.length -gt 104857600} | select-object FullName, @{Name="SizeInMB"; Expression={ [math]::Round($_.length / 1MB,2 )}} | export-csv -notypeinformation -path "C:\temp\Report.csv" | % {$_.Replace('"','')}
```

is there any way to get the CSV report with the following information as well in a separate column?
file extension eg: bak or zip etc

another column with last modified dates of the files

Comment: File objects contain an `Extension` property, which you could just add to your call to `Select-Object`.  e.g. `select-object FullName, @{Name="SizeInMB"; Expression={ [math]::Round($_.length / 1MB,2 )}}, Extension`.  Similarly with `LastWriteTime`, etc.  Use [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.4) to see all the properties available on the file object (or any other PowerShell object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fulfill your need. please check the select-object line

```
Get-childitem -path "C:\Users\someuser" -Include *.db,*.bak,*.mdf,*.ldf,*.zip,*.rar,*.7z -recurse |
    where-object {$_.length -gt 104857600} |
    select-object FullName, @{Name="SizeInMB"; Expression={ [math]::Round($_.length / 1MB,2 )}}, @{Name="File extension"; Expression={($_.Extension).Replace('.','')}} |
    export-csv -notypeinformation -path "C:\temp\Report.csv" | % {$_.Replace('"','')}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked as expected. Is there any way to add the last modified username to the CSV?